# Two definitions of "affine stratification"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

I see two different definitions of "affine stratification" in the literature:

- A stratification where each stratum is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$ for some $n$.
- A stratification where each stratum is an affine variety (or scheme).

This makes searching for information about one or the other annoying.  Is there some additional adjective I can use to specify the former rather than the latter?